# Shortcut to collapse to definitions except regions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

In vs2008, how can I (possibly with a macro) assign a shortcut key to collapse to definitons but leave regions expanded (they must expand if collapsed)?

**EDIT:** I hate regions but my co-workers does not (: So I want this to avoid the regions used by them.

I read jeff's post. Ctrl M + O is what I really want to do, if there were not regions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have *finally* got the answer that I've been looking for, and I think it might help you as well, @Serhat.  You said:

> I read jeff's post. Ctrl M + O is what I really want to do, if there were not regions.

That was *exactly* what I was thinking to myself.  I continued that line of thought and worked on a way to (temporarily) get rid of the #regions.

This isn't a complete solution, but I'm so glad to have *something* that I'm on the verge of jumping up and down.  I will try to make these directions as easy as possible, although I daresay it may simply be easier to post the actual content of the macros I've created. (see link at bottom)

I've created two macros:

1. Comment out all #region and #endregion directives.
2. Uncomment all //#region and //#endregion occurrences.

Create the first macro:

- Start recording a macro with `Ctrl+Shift+R`, and follow these steps:
- `Ctrl+H`, Find what: `#region`, Replace with: `//#region`
- `Alt+A` for Replace All
- `Ctrl+H`, Find what: `#endregion`, Replace with: `//#endregion`
- `Alt+A` for Replace All
- End recording the macro with `Ctrl+Shift+R`
- Open the Macro Explorer with `Alt+F8` or Tools | Macros > Macro Explorer
- Rename TemporaryMacro to CommentRegionDirectives

Then, create the second macro:

- Start recording a macro with `Ctrl+Shift+R`, and follow these steps:
- `Ctrl+H`, Find what: `//#region`, Replace with: `#region`
- `Alt+A` for Replace All
- `Ctrl+H`, Find what: `//#endregion`, Replace with: `#endregion`
- `Alt+A` for Replace All
- End recording the macro with `Ctrl+Shift+R`
- Open the Macro Explorer with `Alt+F8` or Tools | Macros > Macro Explorer
- Rename (this new) TemporaryMacro to UncommentRegionDirectives

Now, save your macros in the Macro Explorer with Ctrl+S.

Finally, assign shortcut keys to the two macros:

- Open Tools | Options | Environment+Keyboard
- In "Show commands containing:" type in `Directives`.  This should show you your two macros, named "Macros.MyMacros.RecordingModule.CommentRegionDirectives" and "...UncommentRegionDirectives"
- Highlight the CommentRegionDirectives entry and in the "Press shortcut keys:" box type `Alt+/` then click the `Assign` button
- Highlight the UncommentRegionDirectives entry and in the "Press shortcut keys:" box type `Alt+Shift+/` then click the `Assign` button (by default these two shortcut combinations are not assigned to anything)
- Click OK to save your shortcut assignments.

Now, when you are faced with auto-collapsed #regions, hit `Alt+/` to comment out the #region directives, and hit the standard `Ctrl+M+O` for Collapse to Definitions (if you so choose).  Then later, before committing that unit with the commented-out #regions, just hit `Alt+Shift+/` to uncomment the #regions and they will be reactivated.

And finally, @Serhat, thank you again for your original comment which put me on this track in the first place.

In practice there is one little hiccup that I am quite willing to live with.  `//#region` followed by `#//endregion` counts as a contiguous comment and comments are still collapsed, but at least there is no code hidden in there.

Here is the promised macro text I extracted from the Macro Explorer: http://pastebin.ca/1688618, although it shouldn't be required if you manually follow the steps I outlined above.

Answer (score 3):

I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is really useful to collapse everything.

Have you read [Jeff's blog post about regions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/)? There's a few more useful shortcuts he lists.

Why do you want to keep these expanded, do you really need the region if you don't want it collapsed?