# Automatically open regions in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, regions

I'd like the regions that show up in my Visual Studio window to be expanded by default when I open a code file. Is this possible in VS2010, or is there an extension that will do that for me?

Barring that, is my request a thing that can be written in an extension?

Comment: The only builtin thing is turning off regions completely. There is limited macro support for defining your own outlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write a macro that calls the Visual Studio Command `Edit.StopOutlining` for you every time you are opening a document.

This MSDN Page describes how to write a basic macro that handles events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1f34as.aspx
Instead of handle the `WindowClosing` you should handle `WindowActivated`.

Like this:

```
Public Sub windowopen(ByVal window As EnvDTE.Window, ByVal lostFocus As EnvDTE.Window) Handles WindowEvents.WindowActivated
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.StopOutlining")
End Sub
```

Of course, this will call `Edit.StopOutlining` on every window you are opening; so maybe you have to do a little bit of filtering what documenttype was activated.

Comment: I suppose if I can't just flip a bit in the preferences, this will have to do.

Comment: Msdn page referenced by article is actually http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1f34as(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you would like Regions turned off, right click any code window, choose `Outlining`, then `Stop Outlining`.

Comment: this kind of works, but I was hoping for a more permanent, global solution.

Comment: See this Visual Studio extension, which automatically expands all regions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115694/how-to-permanently-disable-region-folding-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 2):

There is a free **Visual Studio 2010 extension** which will automatically expand all regions for you:

> **[Auto-Expand Visual Studio Regions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca)**

Please also see this related question:

> [How to permanently disable region-folding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115694/how-to-permanently-disable-region-folding-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 1):

To create a macro that expands all regions for C# files only do the following.

1. Open the Visual Studio Studio Macros window from Tools > Macros > Macros IDE...
2. In the EnvironmentEvents vb file in Project Explorer (if there isn't one then create a new module and it will appear) add the following code after the automatically generated code region

   ```
   Private Sub WindowEvents_WindowActivated(ByVal GotFocus As EnvDTE.Window, ByVal LostFocus As EnvDTE.Window) Handles WindowEvents.WindowActivated
   If GotFocus.Document.FullName.EndsWith(".cs") Then
       DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.StopOutlining")
   End If
   ```

   End Sub
3. Save and Build the project

If you need some more help with macros then read [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1f34as%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information.

There is one issue with this macro that I'm currently working on is that if you click any file in the solution explorer VS will automatically open it.

Answer (score 1):

For newer Visual Studio Versions (such as 2015 but it should also work for 2010) there is an extension called [I hate #Regions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ca60d35-1e02-43b7-bf59-ac7deb9afbca). You can download and install it via *Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online*. It auto expands all regions and lowers the font size of region tags. Hope it helps.