# How to disable code folding in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++-2010, folding

Does anyone know how to disable code folding in Visual C++ 2010?

In the 2008 version I used to disable it by unchecking a certain check box, but this seems to be removed.

I tried to get these [How to permanently disable region-folding in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115694/how-to-permanently-disable-region-folding-in-visual-studio-2008) solutions done, but I can't really get rid of the code folding, in particular the tree node graphics on the left and the text region colors that don't fit my dark color scheme.

Answer (score 29):

Go to Edit → Outlining → Stop Outlining in the Menu Bar.

Comment: As well in VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

## Visual Studio 2019 Update

In VS2019, there is an option to permanently disable outlining for C/C++ files.

### Disable for Every File You Open

Main Menu → Tools → Options... → Text Editor → C/C++ → View → Enable Outlining → set to False

[image: Set Enable Outlining option to False]

### Disable for Current File

Main Menu → Edit → Outlining → Stop Outlining

[image: Disable outlining for current file]

Answer (score 1):

Google search for folding don't give much results, since Microsoft calls this feature "code outlining".

This link contains a simple solution to disable outlining: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/19/turn-off-or-on-outlining-vstipedit0033.aspx