# Visual Studio 2013 C++ outlining / collapsing if/else/while code regions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, collapsable, outlining

Apparently in VS13 they removed the outlining section in Option -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Formatting.

Is there a way of collapsing if/while/etc statements in VS2013 C++? I know about the C# plugin and already got that, but I'm searching for a solution for a C++ enviroment.

Cheers!

Comment: It is still there, Text Editor -> C++ -> View, Outline Statement Blocks.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. I've gone to the hassle of creating an extension that would solve that based on the C# 2013 Outline one . . .

Comment: @HansPassant: Argh! That's an _answer_! :-)

Comment: Hmm, could have sworn it was nothing but a silly oversight.  Let's not document *every* IDE setting in plain sight that somebody is going to overlook some day.

Comment: @Hans: I agree but that's a problem with the question that I don't think should result in answers being posted as comments instead. I'm not aware of any "only post _comments_ to questions of which you disapprove" rule. The Q&A format stands in such situations, unless you opt to close-vote instead.

Comment: viewed: 2666 times

Seems like quite a lot of people are still searching for this one.

Comment: What edition of VS13 you are using? (I mean Express/Community/Pro etc)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Answered by Hans Passant:
"It is still there, Text Editor -> C++ -> View, Outline Statement Blocks"

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio 2013,

---

**Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Formatting -> Outline Statement Blocks -> Enabled.**

Comment: In my case I have VS2013 Professional, this solves the problem.