# How to instruct Visual Studio 2015 to expand all #region sections when it opens file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm working on code base with a lot of #region sections. As they are anti pattern and can hide bugs, I do like to see all regions expanded when I open any C# source file. It there any way to set it up in Visual Studio / ReSharper?

Comment: Not sure about _automatically_ on open, but `Ctrl+M, L` toggles everything expanded/collapsed, and R# has an `Alt+Enter` option to remove all regions in the whole file/project/solution if you want to get rid of them completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hurrah, I found solution, it was answered here: [How to permanently disable region-folding in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115694/how-to-permanently-disable-region-folding-in-visual-studio-2008):

> Go to the Tools->Options menu. Go to Text Editor->C#->Advanced. Uncheck "Enter outlining mode when files open".